# Is there a performance reason to (re)use file descriptors?

Tags: node.js

I use `fs.readFile` and `fs.writeFile` a lot, often repeatedly reading/writing the same file paths.

Would it be better for performance to open each file with `fs.open` once, and then reuse the same `fd` repeatedly (with `fs.read` or `fs.write`)?

Comment: just remember to flush (and wash your hands!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opening a file is a very, very expensive process.  You are best served by keeping the file descriptor active and then just read/write at will.  The only time you need depart from this is when you run short of file descriptors.